# Transfer result from an infinitely looped function to be used by other python functions

Tags: python

I am obtaining continuous data from accelerometer sensor using python function which will run forever (while true loop). In the same function, some calculations will be done and the results will be used by two other python scripts which will also run forever.
For example
First.py will contain a function
*def get():
while True:
data=getAcc
do some complex calculations
return result*

Second.py will contain a function which will display the above result in tkinter window in real time

Third.py will contain function to write above result into text format in real time.
All these scripts should run simultaneously at all times.

I tried to achieve this by importing first script to the rest but this is slowing raspberry pi 3 since second.py and third.py are independently calling the first.py resulting in running first.py  twice every step.
So my question is, is it possible to run first.py independently and let the other two use its result in real time?
I can’t merge these three under same script as all of them are infinite while loops.
I am fairly new to python and moreover the code I have written are too long to post here

Comment: Sounds like you're asking for a parallel processing situation (3 processes running in parallel).  Is that right?  Might be better to do this with an event-driven procedure.

Comment: I concur with @Bill: what you describe is simply parallel processes.  Look up how to do subprocesses and multiprocessing, as well as multithreading.  Your `first` package is the only infinite loop; the other two are event handlers.

Comment: @Bill that’s right to run in parallel. Could you give me some example codes how to achieve this? Maybe a similar example

Comment: @ Prune could you post some examples. The first.py provides result every 10 seconds and the results will contain 5 parameters. The rest two scripts should catch these results in real time and use it their own process without affecting the first.py

Comment: Before going down the parallel processing route, I just wonder if this can be done with an [event-driven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming) approach. Is there any reason why the first function has to have an infinite while loop and not release control to the other functions?

Comment: If `first.py` really does need to be a dedicated process, then why not write the output to a small file and the other process(es) can read the new data from the file when it appears. But I'm not an expert on signal processing applications so there may be a better way.

Comment: @Bill because first script  is getting data from sensor in real-time and the sampling rate is about 125 samples per second. If we break a fraction of a second we will lose data. For instance if vibration (due to earthquake) happens while the script is in release mode, then we would lose the actual reading of the shake. Writing the output of a first script in small file and then let next two scripts get the file is possible. But the next two scripts should also get the data in almost in real time ( maybe 0.002 s delay).

Comment: Okay well that sounds challenging. This might be better to do in a lower-level language like C.  Bear in mind that even with parallel processing, if the other processes are being run on the same CPU, they could interfere with the first process (unless you have a way to prioritize `first.py`).

Comment: You could also try posting the general problem on the [Signal Processing stack exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com). Details about your machine and operating system may come into play. I.e. this may not simply be a Python programming problem.